# how to write data to multiple partitions of topic with Kafka Stream API

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have kafka stream application as mentioned at [How to evaluate consuming time in kafka stream application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109493/how-to-evaluate-consuming-time-in-kafka-stream-application)

With this application, I able to write the data in one partition of a topic. How can I write the data to multiple partitions of a topic? Please help me.

Comment: Do you mean that all partitions are used, i.e. have data written into them? Or do you want the **same** record to be written to multiple partitions of a topic?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Kafka Streams and write data into a topic via `#to(String topicName)` data will be automatically written to "all" partitions. (Ie, each message is written to a single partition but different messages can be written to different partitions.) The partition will be picked via hashing based on the message key. If the key is `null` a random partition is used.

If all your output data has the same key, it would all go to a single partition.

You can also customize the partitioning by using `#to(StreamPartitioner, String)` (old API) or `#to(String, Produced`)` (new API, v1.0+).

Comment: Here key is null. Hence forwarded to only one partition.  Now I able to forward to all partitions by overriding the partition() in StreamPartitioner class

Comment: @Matthias Is there a way to write into all the partitions rather than 1. Basically same data in every partition.

Comment: Well, not really -- a single record will always be written to a single partition -- this is how the `KafkaProducer` works. Thus, if you want to write to all partitions, you would need to duplicate the record first (ie, one copy per partition), and send the different copies to different partitions. However, for Kafka Streams it would require some workarounds to actually do it. -- Wondering _why_ do you want to write a single message to all partitions to begin with? Sounds not like a common pattern to "broadcast" a record.