# What is behaviour of ProcessorContext.getStateStore(String name) & ReadOnlyKeyValueStore.get(String key) in Kafka sream

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have 1.0.0 kafka stream application with two classes as updated at [How to evaluate consuming time in kafka stream application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109493/how-to-evaluate-consuming-time-in-kafka-stream-application). In my application, I read the events, perform some conditional checks and forward to same kafka in another topic. During my evaluation , I am getting some of expressions from Kafka with help of global table store. Observed that most of the time was taken while getting the value from store (sample code is below).

Is it read only one time from Kafka and maintain it in local store? 
or
Is it read from Kafka whenever we call the org.apache.kafka.streams.state.ReadOnlyKeyValueStore.get(String key) API? If yes then how to maintain local store instead of read everytime from Kafka?

Please help.

Ex:

```
private KeyValueStore<String, List<String>> policyStore = (KeyValueStore<String, List<String>>) this.context
                            .getStateStore(policyGlobalTableName);

List<String> policyIds = policyStore.get(event.getCustomerCode());
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, stores use an application local RocksDB instance to buffer data. Thus, if you query the store with a `get()` it will not go over the network and not the brokers, but only the local RocksDB.

You can try to change RocksDB setting to improve the performance, but I have no guidelines atm which configs you might wanna change. Configuring RocksDB is a quite tricky thing. But you might want to search the Internet for further information about it.

You can pass in RocksDB configs via `StreamsConfig` (cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#rocksdb-config-setter)

As an alternative, you could also try to reconfigure Streams to use in-memory stores instead of RocksDB. Note, that this will increase your rebalance time, as there is no local buffered state if you use in-memory instead of RocksDB. (cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#defining-and-creating-a-state-store)